# Generate multiple result in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Currently I am working on one Web-based software which creates results automatically in codeigniter. I create modules like add student, add marks & generate mark sheet. here in generate marksheet i created individual marksheet but now I want to generate code for generate marksheet on one button click.

For that i use file_get_content(), curl(), fopen() but this all showing blank page if `file_get_content("http://127.0.0.1/exam/admission/forms/showResult/41/2/1")`

shows individual students result i want to show it in page

Here is My controller code

```
class forms extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->admin_layout->setLayout('template/layout_admission');

        $session = $this->session->userdata('admin_session');
        if (empty($session) || $session->type != 'admission') {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Login First');
            redirect(base_url() . 'login', 'refresh');
        }

    function printDoc(){
        $siteaddressAPI = "http://127.0.0.1/exam/admission/forms/showResult/41/2/1";
        $data = file_get_contents($siteaddressAPI);
        echo $data;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think you need to call that controller with student id by clicking on button using ajax. That would solve the problem.

Comment: I tried to call controller file_get_contents() but it is also showing blank page

Comment: you don't need file_get_contents() for that. you need to call your url "http://127.0.0.1/exam/admission/forms/showResult/41/2/1" from ajax request and it will respond with the result.

Comment: if you have tried running `http://127.0.0.1/exam/admission/forms/showResult/41/2/1` directly from your browser and it is still showing a blank page, then the problem lies on the code you are using. However, we cannot know what the problem is unless you provide us with the code you use here. Edit your Original Post and include you controller's method code.

Answer (score 0):

Your Question does not explain exactly what you need.!!! Better you can give your sample code with expected result.

Still I have a solution which might help you in some way.

You can use view template to generate mark-sheet code. For Example:

```
$mark_sheets = array();
foreach($all_students_data as $student_data){
    $mark_sheets[] = $this -> load -> view('marksheet_template', $student_data, TRUE);
}
```

Here `$this -> load -> view()` with third parameter `TRUE` will return generated html code and then store it in mark_sheets array.

By this way, you can access all your mark-sheets from `$mark_sheets` array.

Comment: Need **Sample Code** with Your Expected Result for more better answer.

Comment: "_more better_" ? Sorry, I had to.

Comment: I have answered this question based on my assumption of given questioned data. So "more better" or can say a specific problem oriented answer can be given if the problem definition is specific or with clear sample code.

Comment: I know what you were trying to say.. I was just being anal about your english.. _"more better"_ is not proper english: https://www.englishforums.com/English/CanMoreBetterBeCorrect/vwqhd/post.htm

Comment: Thanks @CodeGodie. I will take care of it and not to use such words.